# Add string when column equals to specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @comando as varchar(5000)

    set @comando = 'DTEXEC  /FILE \"" /de "pass" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EW'
    select @comando = @comando + ' /SET "\"\Package.Variables[' + Replace(str_NombreVariable,'User::','') + '].Value\"";' 
   + str_ValorVariable + ''
from [Catalogo].[catVariablesEtl] where IdPaquete = 42
```

I receive large item like this:

```
DTEXEC  /FILE \"" /de "pass" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EW /SET "\"\Package.Variables[v_sTipoCarga].Value\"";M /SET "\"\Package.Variables[v_sUsuarioCarga].Value\"";0 /SET "\"\Package.Variables[v_sCadenaConexion].Value\"";"\"Data Source=0.0.0.0.0\DB;User ID=BB;Password=BBA;Initial Catalog=BS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=BBS;Persist Security Info=True;\"" /SET "\"\Package.Variables[v_sCadenaConexionSAP].Value\"";"\"TYPE=A; ASHOST=0.0.0.0.0; SYSNR=70; CLIENT=720; LANG=ES; USER=BB; PASSWD=BB1;\"" /SET "\"\Package.Variables[v_sRutaArchivo].Value\"";"\"\\0.0.0.0\SIBISharedFolder\Source\CargaMaquinas\ /SET "\"\Package.Variables[v_IdBitacoraCarga].Value\"";0
```

Penultimate value have `Package.Variables[v_sRutaArchivo].Value` and `str_ValorVariable` equals to `\\0.0.0.0\SIBISharedFolder\Source\CargaMaquinas\`, I want to know if its possible to add a string to this select by search this item: `v_sRutaArchivo` in `str_NombreVariable` and when it found add to `str_ValorVariable` value `.csv`

Is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @comando as varchar(5000)

set @comando = 'DTEXEC  /FILE \"" /de "pass" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EW'
select @comando = @comando + ' /SET "\"\Package.Variables[' + Replace(str_NombreVariable,'User::','') + '].Value\"";' 
   + str_ValorVariable + CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable like '%v_sRutaArchivo%' THEN '.csv' ELSE '' END + ''
from [Catalogo].[catVariablesEtl] where IdPaquete = 42
```

Comment: are you there? @Element Zero